# Validating if a Particular String is available in the Response Body

Tags: citrus-framework

The Response data contains something like this.
"INBOUND_MESSAGE:

HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type:application/json
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Date:Fri, 22 Sep 2017 12:18:50 GMT

## {"errors":{"deviceId":{"message":"Path `deviceId` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","properties":{"type":"required","message":"Path `{PATH}` is required.","path":"deviceId","value":""},"kind":"required","path":"deviceId","value":"","$isValidatorError":true},"name":{"message":"Path `name` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","properties":{"type":"required","message":"Path `{PATH}` is required.","path":"name","value":""},"kind":"required","path":"name","value":"","$isValidatorError":true}},"_message":"devices validation failed","message":"devices validation failed: deviceId: Path `deviceId` is required., name: Path `name` is required.","name":"ValidationError"}

"

Where i need to see if i can validate against $.Message and condition has to be "deviceId` is required". I used the below piece of code however the testcase is failing since multiple Messages are Available on $.Message

```
            http()
                .client(IotDevice)
                .receive()
                .response(HttpStatus.OK)
                .validate("$.message", "Path `deviceId` is required.");
```

Is there a Way to Search the Intended String inside the Response Message.

Regards
BJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Clarification on JSONPath

By using the JSONPath expression `$.message` you are *not* selecting multiple `message` entries, but exactly the one under the root (you *could* select all  using `$..message`, with two dots).

If look at your JSON data in a formatted way, you can instantly see the value of the top-most `message` entry is `devices validation failed: deviceId: Path deviceId is required., name: Path name is required.` which seems to be a concatenation of all the messages within the `errors` section.

#### Solution

So, if your goal is to validate that the string `Path deviceId is required` is part of the top-most `message` entry, you can use the following Citrus matcher in combination with your JSONPath expression (see also Citrus documentation on [JSONPath](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#validate-with-jsonpath) and [validation matchers](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html#validation-matcher)):

```xml
<message type="json">
  <validate>
    <json-path expression="$.message" value="@contains('Path deviceId is required')@"/>
  </validate>
</message>
```

#### Formatted JSON

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "deviceId": {
      "message": "Path deviceId is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path {PATH} is required.",
        "path": "deviceId",
        "value": ""
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "deviceId",
      "value": "",
      "$isValidatorError": true
    },
    "name": {
      "message": "Path name is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "Path {PATH} is required.",
        "path": "name",
        "value": ""
      },
      "kind": "required",
      "path": "name",
      "value": "",
      "$isValidatorError": true
    }
  },
  "_message": "devices validation failed",
  "message": "devices validation failed: deviceId: Path deviceId is required., name: Path name is required.",
  "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Much gucce, I wonder how to put it in the Script. Any help is much Appreciated

Comment: How to use the  (<value>@contains('foo')@</value>) in Java DSL